# Endless loop after exceeding the value range of the int

Tags: c++, windows

I have programmed a decimal to binary converter and used the datatype unsigned long long int. Additionally I have a while loop so that I can convert a number again after the conversion. **Why do I come into an endless loop if I exceed the value range of the unsigned long long int?**

My guess is that the loop has no condition what to do if there is an error and therefore keeps the bool true.

**And how can I catch an error like this?**

*Here is the function that contains the loop*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

void calculateBinary();

int main()
{
    bool programmRun = true;
    while (programmRun)
    {
        calculateBinary();
    }
}

void calculateBinary()
{
    unsigned long long int number;
    unsigned long long int binary;
    unsigned long long int division;
    unsigned long long int memory;
    unsigned long long int preDivision;
    unsigned long long int runs = 0;
    unsigned long long int* binaryArray;
    unsigned long long int runsMemory;

    bool arraySort = false;
    bool calculate = true;

    std::cout << "Number to convert: ";
    std::cin >> number;

    memory = number;

    while (calculate)
    {
        preDivision = memory / 2;
        memory = preDivision;

        runs++;

        if (preDivision == 0)
        {
            calculate = false;
            runsMemory = runs - 1;
            binaryArray = new unsigned long long int[runs];

            for (unsigned int k = 0; k < runs; k++)
            {
                binaryArray[k] = k;
            }

            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < runs; i++)
            {
                division = number / 2;
                binary = number % 2;
                number = division;
                binaryArray[runsMemory--] = binary;
            }

            std::cout << "Converted number: ";

            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < runs; j++)
            {
                std::cout << binaryArray[j];
            }

            delete[] binaryArray;
            std::cout << "\n" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In this code, you never change `programRun`.  Please provide a [mcve] that shows the problem.

Comment: In order to be able to help you, if would be useful seeing the source code of the `calculateBinary()` function.

Comment: The scant, shown code, is an obvious infinite loop. If you are a complete stranger who doesn't know anything about the program being described, and only sees what's shown in the question, what conclusion would you make?

Comment: I cannot even imagine how the `calculateBinary()` method is supposed to change the `programmRun` local variable?  It seems to be technically impossible even.

Comment: So I reworked the whole thing and inserted the whole source code. I just thought that the previous one would be enough to answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a litte check if the user wants to continue converting the numbers. The problem was your `while` loop in `main()` checking a variable which is never changed. Use something like this:

```cpp
int main() {
    char ch = 'Y';
    while (ch == 'Y' or ch == 'y') {
        calculateBinary();
        std::cout << "\nWanna convert another number?? (Y/N) ";
        std::cin >> ch;
    }
}
```

PS: If you'd enabled compiler warnings you must have got what was wrong with your code.